# saving voxel grid from a specific viewpoint

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, voxel

**Problem statement:** I have numpy array of shape (128,128,128), which is my binary voxel grid of 0s and 1s. An object is represented in this cube.

I want to save the occupancy of the object into another numpy array of (128,128,128) when viewed from a specific viewpoint, i.e. when I move my camera/visualizer the voxels will appear in different positions from the 'canonical', so in the voxel grid the 1s will have different indices/positions.

Anyone knows how to do this?

**What I'm trying now:** I've loaded my numpy array converted to xyz coordinates the points that are occupied (the 1s), used open3d to visualise them as point cloud (similarly to what they do [here](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html)). Then I am manipulating the camera position in open3d to have a different view of the object. But how can I then save what I see as a voxel grid style numpy array.

Another way I've thought was to actually rotate the object instead.

If you know other better ways, using other softwares it's fine as well as long as it's compatible with python and scalable.

Comment: Why the voxel grid should be different from another viewpoint? At first glance the world (voxel grid) is not dependent on my position (viewpoint)

Comment: if you consider the world coordinates they do not change position in fact, but if your reference system is the camera than they should change.

Comment: Moving the camera is the same as rotating and/or translating the voxels. Search for graphics programming maths (also, plenty of OpenGL tutorials), using 4x4 matrices.